# Eclipse - easy way to access right-clickable properties from Package Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

I have this workflow problem in Eclipse (Java) in which there are of course hundreds of files in my package explorer.  I know I can use `Ctrl+R` to open a file which is great - however from the tab I can't right click and do things like `Compare With`, `Team > Commit` and dozens of other useful options I need.  Which leads to me browsing for the file in the package explorer - it's not like the file appears in package explorer when I `Ctrl+R` it - which is an annoying workflow problem.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Maybe i am missing something in the question :) but if you do Ctrl+R (or Ctrl+Shift+R) and the link with editor, then you probably find the file in Package Explorer and then right click on the file itself in the tree, would that not work?

Comment: The package explorer is completely unchanged when I Ctrl+R (R is already capital, right?).  If it did what you are describing that would be completely fine.

Comment: Yep, sorry, did not see the capital; did you try link with editor as i advised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered package explorer actually has a yellow left/right arrow looking button that will open the current file in package explorer.  This is the feature I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click inside the file editor after opening with Ctrl-R (or Command-Shift-R on Macs) to use Compare With and Team -- most options from Package Explorer are available as context options in the Java file editor.